# Sort html string in alphabetical order using PHP

Tags: php

See code below. I want to sort the option tags by name, not by id.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$string = '<option id=a1>Sinead Shannon Roche<option id=a2>Emile Abossolo Mbo<option id=a3>Youssouf Djaoro<option id=a4>Dioucounda Koma';
$new_string = '';

$s = explode('<', $string);
asort($s);
foreach($s AS $v) {
    $new_string = $new_string . '<' . $v;
}

// I want $new_string to be "<option id=a4>Dioucounda Koma<option id=a2>Emile Abossolo Mbo<option id=a1>Sinead Shannon Roche<option id=a3>Youssouf Djaoro"

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery for this myself...

If you are intrested heres the code.

Declare a global function

```
$.fn.sortSelect = function() {
    var op = this.children("option");
    op.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text > b.text ? 1 : -1;
    })
    return this.empty().append(op);
}
```

And call the function from the code.

```
$("#my_select").sortSelect();
```